# the trait `From<xcm::v3::NetworkId>` is not implemented for `AccountId`

Tags: parachain, xcm, relay-chain

I was making a new way to add sovereign accounts for a particular Network ID. Like in this https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/blob/HEAD/xcm/xcm-builder/src/location_conversion.rs

```
pub struct ChildParachainConvertsVia<ParaId, AccountId>(PhantomData<(ParaId, AccountId)>);
impl<ParaId: From<u32> + Into<u32> + AccountIdConversion<AccountId>, AccountId: Clone>
    Convert<MultiLocation, AccountId> for ChildParachainConvertsVia<ParaId, AccountId>
{
    fn convert_ref(location: impl Borrow<MultiLocation>) -> Result<AccountId, ()> {
        match location.borrow() {
            MultiLocation { parents: 0, interior: X1(Parachain(id)) } =>
                Ok(ParaId::from(*id).into_account_truncating()),
            _ => Err(()),
        }
    }

    fn reverse_ref(who: impl Borrow<AccountId>) -> Result<MultiLocation, ()> {
        if let Some(id) = ParaId::try_from_account(who.borrow()) {
            Ok(Parachain(id.into()).into())
        } else {
            Err(())
        }
    }
}
```

It is a way to add sovereign account of Parachain in the Relay chain. There are also other examples where we can add sibling sovereign account also.  I was making a new way to add sovereign account of particular NetworkId.

```
pub struct NetworkIdConvertsVia<Network, AccountId>(PhantomData<(Network, AccountId)>);
impl<Network: Get<NetworkId>, AccountId: From<[u8; 32]> + Into<[u8; 32]> + Clone >
    Convert<MultiLocation, AccountId> for NetworkIdConvertsVia<Network, AccountId> where xcm::v3::NetworkId: From<AccountId>
{

    fn convert(location: MultiLocation) -> Result<AccountId, MultiLocation> {
         let id = match location {

           MultiLocation { parents: 0, interior: X1(GlobalConsensus(network)) }  => network,  
        _=>return Err(location)
       };
       Ok(id.into())
    
    }

    // fn reverse(who: AccountId) -> Result<MultiLocation, AccountId> {
    // //Ok(GlobalConsensus(NetworkId()).into())
    // )
    // }
```

But I'm getting error "the trait `From<xcm::v3::NetworkId>` is not implemented for `AccountId`">please check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error message suggests that you are trying to use an AccountId as a NetworkId in a call to the Cross-Consensus Message (XCM) module in the Substrate blockchain framework.

The From trait is a standard Rust trait that is used to define conversions between types. In this case, the Fromxcm::v3::NetworkId trait is required to convert an AccountId into a NetworkId type, which is used to identify the target network of a cross-chain message in the XCM protocol.

To resolve this error, you need to ensure that the AccountId is properly converted to a NetworkId before it is used in the XCM call. You can do this using the TryFrom trait from the sp_std::convert module, which allows you to attempt to convert between types and handle errors if the conversion fails.

Here's an example of how you can use TryFrom to convert an AccountId to a NetworkId:

```
use sp_std::convert::TryFrom;
```

use xcm::v3::{NetworkId, AccountId32};

// Convert an AccountId to a NetworkId
let account_id = AccountId32::new([0u8; 32]); // Replace with your AccountId
let network_id = NetworkId::try_from(account_id.clone()).map_err(|_| "Invalid network ID")?;

// Use the NetworkId in an XCM call
let message = xcm::v3::Xcm::WithdrawAsset(xcm::v3::WithdrawAsset {
assets: vec![xcm::v3::MultiAsset::ConcreteFungible(xcm::v3::FungibleAsset {
id: [1u8; 32].into(),
amount: 100.into(),
})],
effects: xcm::v3::WithdrawAssetEffects::Transfer(xcm::v3::Transact {
origin_type: xcm::v3::OriginKind::SovereignAccount,
origin: account_id.into(),
require_weight_at_most: 100_000_000,
call: xcm::v3::Call::System(xcm::v3::SystemCall::Remark(vec![1, 2, 3])),
}),
dest: xcm::v3::MultiLocation::X1(
xcm::v3::Junction::AccountId32 {
network: network_id.clone(),
id: [2u8; 32].into(),
}
.into(),
),
signer: xcm::v3::Signer::Sovereign(account_id),
strategy: xcm::v3::WithdrawStrategy::All,
max_payment: 100_000_000_000_000,
});

// Send the XCM message
xcm::send_xcm(message.into()).map_err(|_| "Failed to send XCM message")?;